# Appending anchor tag to next post

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am making a one page wordpress site. There is a section of the website displaying content via category posts. There is only one post displaying at a time and I am using the following default code to have Next/Prev links appear:

```
<div class="alignleft"><?php next_posts_link('&laquo; Next Recipe') ?></div>
<div class="alignright"><?php previous_posts_link('Previous Recipe &raquo;') ?></div>
```

When the previous post is clicked, it loads the previous post properly, however since this is a one page site, it goes to the top of the page upon refresh.

Is there a way when that link is clicked, to make it refresh the page in the same location, or to target  that I would like? Even better, a way to make this do a page refresh using AJAX? I've crawled google and haven't found anything.

I suppose this is similar: http://www.problogdesign.com/wordpress/load-next-wordpress-posts-with-ajax/, however I haven't been able to execute that with my custom theme.

Comment: How do you have a one-page site if you are not already using AJAX?

Comment: I have 4 pages and I use the get_pages and conditional statements to get 4 of the pages. I have the links at the top pointing to anchor tags above each page in the code. It's actually really simple how I have it setup.

Comment: I guess you don't mean ["single page interface"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) which is what it sounded like to me.

Comment: Ah, my apologies for the explanation. Essentially this is a website that has an about section, a section that displays content using custom fields and category posts (so the user can essentially update the content by making a new post). A section that has more information, and a contact. It's quite simple at the core of it. Basically a simple website, but displaying the content on one page instead of four. I've figured out that bit, I am trying to solve the prev/next issue so when clicked it stays in that region of the page instead of going to the top on refresh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can alter the links for `next_post_link` and `previous_post_link` with a filter.

```
function alter_npppl_wpse_100919($link) {
  return preg_replace('/href="([^"]+)"/','href="$1#something"',$link);
}
add_filter('next_post_link','alter_npppl_wpse_100919');
add_filter('previous_post_link','alter_npppl_wpse_100919');
```

The URL you get will be the default URL plus `#content`. If your site is generating `/page/2/` then the final URL will be `/page/2/#content`. If you don't want that trailing slash-- the one before the `#`-- you will have to pass the match through a callback.

```
function alter_npppl_noslash_cb_wpse_100919($match) {
  return 'href="'.untrailingslashit($match[1]).'#content"';
}
function alter_npppl_v2_wpse_100919($link) {
  return preg_replace_callback('/href="([^"]+)"/','alter_npppl_noslash_cb_wpse_100919',$link);
}
function alter_npppl_wpse_100919($link) {
  return preg_replace('/href="([^"]+)"/','href="$1#something"',$link);
}
add_filter('next_post_link','alter_npppl_v2_wpse_100919');
add_filter('previous_post_link','alter_npppl_v2_wpse_100919');
```

If you site is using the trailing slash I would not remove it. You will likely end up with unnecessary redirects if you do.

`#something` can be any `id` on the page. If you had `<div id="content"` then adding `#content` should cause that `div` to scroll into view on page load.

Comment: I put this in my function.php. After this is inserted, should I expect the permalink if I view source to change from page/3/ to page/3#something ?

Comment: `page/3/#something` actually, but basically yes.

Comment: @James : See the edit. See the Codex for getting starting with AJAX and there are a lot of questions here about it too. Search, see what you can come up with and then my advise would be to start a new question with your code, working or not, and a specific question about a problem with it.